# Spring boot running as container issues

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, amazon-aurora

I am running a spring boot with REST API inside a docker container. Everything seems to work fine when i run from eclipse or as jar. But when i dockerize it and run i am facing below issues

**First**
Not able to access REST Endpoint within container.

`http://localhost:9000/`  --> works But

`http://localhost:9000/api/v1/test` --> it does not identify.

However i can run it from swagger.

**Second issue** org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for schema   < schema_name >

However i have given all permissions for the schema like

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA < schemaname> TO < username>;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA < schemaname> TO < username>;
```

These issues are only when i try to run from a container.

Commands use for docker

`docker run -p 9000:9000  < image name >`

Am using spring boot 2.1.9

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD run-app.sh run-app.sh
RUN chmod +x run-app.sh
EXPOSE 9000
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} dummy.jar
ENTRYPOINT ./run-app.sh
```

**run-app.sh**

```
java  $JAVA_OPTS -jar /dummy.jar
```

**My postgresql Db is running in aws.**

My spring boot is able to start, but only while my API is querying i am facing the exception

Comment: [Second issue] Are you referring to your database with **localhost** inside the container?

Here is a project of mine with spring-boot & postgres running in docker if the config could be of any help: https://github.com/choudharyhimanshu/survey-panda-api

Comment: what error you get for your first issue?

Comment: Hi, my db is running in aws.

Comment: First issue is fine, am able to run via curl command, only in postman i am facing, so not bothered about it much

Answer (score 0):

Can you share dockerfile content if possible, would like to see what commands you have given with endpoints. and for postgresql which you are using, is it embeded in docker with spring boot app or another server?

I do already setup spring boot with nginx and postgresql dockerized but in different servers/containers which working pretty smooth on production.

Comment: How you built docker image?

Comment: docker build  -t <imagename>:latest .

Answer (score 0):

For first issue I will need more details.

For second issue, the problem is two containers are not on the same network and hence service container can't communicate with psql container. You can actually create a `docker-compose.yml` file to run those on same network. Or create a network and join the containers on that network.

Comment: postresql is running in aws. and spring boot container is running in my localhost.  Can you share any examples of docker-compose.yml related to my usecase

Comment: and more over if its network issue, then my app should not start in first place. its able to communicate but only while querying i am facing this issue.

Comment: you never mentioned that in question. please update the question